# Recover content from strapi using nuxtjs api

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi

System Information

- **Strapi** Version*3.*
- **Operating System**: MacOs Big Sur
- **Database**: MariaDB
- **Node Version**:v14.17.0
- **NPM Version**: 6.14.13
- **Yarn Version**: 1.22.5

---

Hi everybody, I have some difficulties to recover content inside a strapi table in a Nuxtjs API.
I'd like to recover content in locations: `location_id: 49`
this is the table:

```js
[
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Legal notice',
    description: 'Hello',
    date: '2021-06-01',
    locale: 'fr-FR',
    created_at: '2021-06-21T20:27:23.000Z',
    updated_at: '2021-06-22T13:07:14.000Z',
    location: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'toto',
      location_id: 49,
      locale: 'fr-FR',
      created_at: '2021-06-21T20:30:31.000Z',
      updated_at: '2021-06-21T20:33:44.000Z'
    },
    localizations: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Test cell',
    description: 'csdcmsdml',
    date: '2021-06-06',
    locale: 'fr-FR',
    created_at: '2021-06-22T14:10:29.000Z',
    updated_at: '2021-06-22T14:10:29.000Z',
    location: null,
    localizations: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract the first object, right?
Let's say that our array is called `array`, this will do it.

```js
this.array.filter(element => element.location?.location_id === 49)
```

`?.` is useful here because of the `location: null` case, which will otherwise throw an error.
It's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Answer (score 0):

I want to recover description in all langues I wrote it and I need recover the content of description according with location

this is a capture of my content-type on strapi:
[image: content type from strapi]

I have 4 fields, I need description and location.
this is my request in nuxtjs:

```
async asyncData({ app, i18n, $md }: any) {  
       const data = await app.$strapi.find('legal-notices', {
      _locale: i18n.localeProperties.iso })
```

Actually I have the content of description in english and french but it is not linked with location, this is my problem.

thanks for your attention and your help.